# Adding an ordered day of week variable

Tags: r

Data set g

```
DayofWeek   Date    Imp Clicks  Credit
Monday     30JUN03  130   9     $2.58
Tuesday    01JUL03  313  28     $5.04
Wednesday  02JUL03  201  10     $0.84
Thursday   03JUL03  400  32     $3.84
Friday     04JUL03  368  15     $4.28
Saturday   05JUL03  272  25     $9.04
```

Data set g.  I needed to add tabs so it would run

```
DayofWeek   Date    Imp Clicks  Credit
Monday     30JUN03  130   9     $2.58
Tuesday    01JUL03  313  28     $5.04
Wednesday     02JUL03   201  10     $0.84
Thursday       03JUL03  400  32     $3.84
Friday     04JUL03  368  15     $4.28
Saturday       05JUL03  272  25     $9.04


dirdata<-"C:/data/"
df=read.table(paste0(dirdata,"g.txt"),
header=TRUE, 
sep="\t",
stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

names(df)
head(df,5)
dim(df)
df=cbind(Day,df)
summary(df)
head(df,10)

# define an ordered day-of-week variable Day
  df$Day <- with(data=df,
  ifelse ((DayofWeek == "Monday"),1,
  ifelse ((DayofWeek == "Tuesday"),2,
  ifelse ((DayofWeek == "Wednesday"),3,
  ifelse ((DayofWeek == "Thursday"),4,
  ifelse ((DayofWeek == "Friday"),5,
  ifelse ((DayofWeek == "Saturday"),6,
  ifelse ((DayofWeek == "Sunday"),7,))))))))

Error in ifelse((DayofWeek == "Sunday"), 7, ) : 
  argument "no" is missing, with no default
```

I think I need to add in the no condition but I am not sure where and have it still have correct syntax.

I think the following are easier but I get an error invalid factor levels.

```
if(DayofWeek=="Monday")   (Day <- "1.Monday")
if(DayofWeek=="Tuesday")  (Day <- "2.Tuesday")
if(DayofWeek=="Wednesday")(Day <- "3.Wednesday")
if(DayofWeek=="Thursday") (Day <- "4.Thursday")
if(DayofWeek=="Friday")   (Day <- "5.Friday")
if(DayofWeek=="Saturday") (Day <- "6.Saturday")
if(DayofWeek=="Sunday")   (Day <- "7.Sunday")
```

or

```
df.new<-within(df,{
Day[DayofWeek=="Monday"]    <- "_1.Monday"
Day[DayofWeek=="Tuesday"]   <- "_2.Tuesday"
Day[DayofWeek=="Wednesday"] <- "_3.Wednesday"
Day[DayofWeek=="Thursday"]  <- "_4.Thursday"
Day[DayofWeek=="Friday"]    <- "_5.Friday"
Day[DayofWeek=="Saturday"]  <- "_6.Saturday"
Day[DayofWeek=="Sunday"]    <- "_7.Sunday" })
```

or

```
df.new<-within(df,{
Day[DayofWeek=="Monday"]    <- "a1Monday"
Day[DayofWeek=="Tuesday"]   <- "a2Tuesday"
Day[DayofWeek=="Wednesday"] <- "a3Wednesday"
Day[DayofWeek=="Thursday"]  <- "a4Thursday"
Day[DayofWeek=="Friday"]    <- "a5Friday"
Day[DayofWeek=="Saturday"]  <- "a6Saturday"
Day[DayofWeek=="Sunday"]    <- "a7Sunday" })
```

Any help you can give would be appreciated. Thank you. MM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to handle this but what I would have done is convert `Date` column to date object and use `format` to get day of the week

```
as.integer(format(as.Date(df$Date, "%d%b%y"), "%u"))
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Using `lubridate` that can be done as

```
library(lubridate)
wday(dmy(df$Date))
```

However, note that for base R version using `format` "Monday" is treated as 1 and with `lubridate` `wday` "Sunday" is 1. You need to adjust the output based on your preference.

Comment: date-time format conversion table in RSSU by Muenchen says %U gives week of the  year and %w = day of the week 0-6, Sunday=0. Will %w also work correctly? Thanks. MM

Comment: For R, all the formats are given at `?strptime`. `%w` gives numbers from 0-6 where 0 is Sunday.

Comment: Ok.  I will be using ? in R more often! Thanks. MM